# Rouer outlet *ngIF

Tags: angular

I have the following app structure:

master.html - my app component HTML template structure:

```
<header>
<sidebar-right>
<sidebar-left>

<router-outlet>

<footer>
```

Now.. I have 2 scenarios:

1. Guests
2. Logged in user

If the user is a guest, I need to display the `<intro></intro>` component without the sidebars, and if the user is a logged in member, show the router outlet with all those tags (sidebars, header, etc..)

How I can do that? Since I can't use the `router outlet` inside `*ngIf`, I have no idea how to make it work the way described above.

Any ideas?

Desired output idea:

```
<section *ngIf="loggedIn">
<header>
    <sidebar-right>
    <sidebar-left>

    <router-outlet>

    <footer>
</section>
<section *ngIf="!loggedIn">
<intro></intro>
</section>
```

Comment: You can use 2 different routes and when logged in for example display an empty dummy component.

Comment: Does't sound like the perfect solution, but if it's the best way - Any reference about how using multiple routes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Multiple routes is the most common use case. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I dont understand. Even if I have 2 routes, how I can make my application know which route is for members and which route is for guests, since router outlet is not allowed inside ngIf? Is there any way you can give more specific answer to my app structure?

Comment: Sorry, I also don't understand your questions :D No idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

**Put the Guest View and the User View in two different routes and then add a Route Guard,** which will serve as a condition for a route being viewable. This does what the *ngIf would have if it worked on the router-outlet tag.

Move the contents that you want the Logged-In user to see out of the app component HTML template and into a component of its own. Do the same for the contents for the Guest User.

Add both components as routes in your route configuration and set the 'canActivate' value of the component for Logged-In user to an imported 'authentication guard service'(that you will create):

```
import { AuthGuardService } from '../auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'guest',
    component: guestComponent
  },
  { path: 'logged-in-user',
    component: loggedInUserComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  }
];
```

Create the Guard Service:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  loggedIn: boolean; 

  canActivate() {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }
}
```

The loggedInUser component can only be navigated to and viewed if the loggedIn value is true.

You can find this and more the documentation on the angular.io site:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards